# regex: split by + except if inside a brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm dealing with equations like `'x_{t+1}+y_{t}=z_{t-1}'`. My objective is to obtain all "variables", that is, a list with `x_{t+1}, y_{t}, z_{t-1}`.

I'd like to split the string by `[+-=*/]`, but not if + or - are inside `{}`.

Something like this `re.split('(?<!t)[\+\-\=]','x_{t+1}+y_{t}=z_{t-1}')` partly does the job by not spliting if it observes `t` followed by a symbol. But I'd like to be more general. Assume there are no nested brackets.

How can I do this?

Comment: Regular expressions are not very good for this operation.

Comment: Do you have nested brackets?

Comment: Do all variables have subscripts?

Comment: Assume not! In the future I might want to substitute \frac{num}{den} for (num)/(den), but that's another story... For the moment I won't use \frac{}{}

Comment: All variables take the form `a_{t+b}`. Where `a` does not need to be only one letter, it can be `pi`, and `+b` will be +1, -1, or simply blank.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting at those characters, you could find sequences of all *other* characters (like `x` and `_`) and bracket parts (like `{t+1}`). The first such sequence in the example is `x`, `_`, `{t+1}`, i.e., the substring `x_{t+1}`.

```
import re

s = 'x_{t+1}+y_{t}=z_{t-1}'

print(re.findall(r'(?:\{.*?}|[^-+=*/])+', s))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurWMFWQb0ivrpE27BWuxJI19pWAUldw1p1Lq6Cosy8Eo2iVL20zLyUxJwcjSJ1DXurmGo9Lfvamug4XW1bLf1YTW11HYViTc3//wE)):

```
['x_{t+1}', 'y_{t}', 'z_{t-1}']
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `re.split`, consider using `re.findall` to match only the variables:

```
>>> re.findall(r"[a-z0-9]+(?:_\{[^\}]+\})?","x_{t+1}+y_{t}=z_{t-1}+pi", re.IGNORECASE)
['x_{t+1}', 'y_{t}', 'z_{t-1}', 'pi']
```

[Try online](https://regex101.com/r/hrVxH4/1)

Explanation of regex:

```
[a-z0-9]+(?:_\{[^\}]+\})?
[a-z0-9]+                : One or more alphanumeric characters
         (?:           )?: A non-capturing group, optional
            _\{      \}  : Underscore, and opening/closing brackets
               [^\}]+    : One or more non-close-bracket characters
```